# How to make debounce in js

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js

I have a function like below in Vuejs.

When you click button, 'start()' runs and function rn() runs also.
But '`const` command' is being changed during 0.1sec, 3sec, 2sec or 2sec on just one button click.
That is 'button' is clicked just one, but 'command' is being changed a lot on short time.
But when the command isn't changed more than 3sec, I hope the Axios post runs.
Even though I tried using Lodash debounce, I have not found the solution. 
Could you help me how to solve this? Thank you so much for reading.

```
<template>
    <button @click="start()">Start</button>
</tempalte>

methods:{
    start() {
        ..
        ..
        ..
        function rn() {
           const command = something..
           ..
           axios.post('localhost:4000', {data: command})
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How were you using lodash debounce?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it naive way.

```js
const ELAPSE_TIME = 3000; // 3 second
let oldCommand;
let lastTime;

function update() {
   if (buttonIsPressed) {
       const command = getCurrentCommand();

       if (command !== oldCommand) { // command has changed
           lastTime = new Date().getTime();
       } else { // command has not changed
           let now = new Date().getTime();
           let duration = now - lastTime;

           if (duration > ELAPSE_TIME) { // already 3 second
               postUpdate();
               lastTime = now - ELAPSE_TIME;
           }
       }
   }
}


setInterval(update, 100);
```